# Getting TypeError: Unknown encoding: 1 while running the server script with Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I am running the following code to insert fruit names into the database with Mongoose. It does insert the object but then it throws a **TypeError: Unknown encoding: 1** and exits the script. I tried updating Mongoose and Mongo but it did not solve the problem.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var assert = require('assert');
var Fruits = require('./models/fruits-1');
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/confusion';
mongoose.connect(url);
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function(){
    Fruits.create(
        {
            name: 'Apple',
            description: "It's delicious."
        }, function(err, fruit){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            }
            else{
                console.log(fruit);
            }
    });
});
```

[image]

Comment: What is there at line number 24 on your `server-2.js` file? Error seems to be originating from there.

Comment: @BlazeSahlzen sorry but there are only 21 lines in my code which I have posted above.

Comment: Likely this [issue](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4864) with mongoose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a bad working solution, remove console.log(fruit).

I had the same problem now on Fedora 25, with the same kind of code. 
And it worked normally sooner today on Ubuntu 14.04.

Both of them are using Nvm with v6.

Comment: Wow it worked, any clue why it wouldn't let us log the object we just entered? Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: It's probably the issue linked by Blaze Sahlzen in the comments of your question. 
I actually use bson 1.0.2, you too probably.

Answer (score 3):

The real solution is to update your bson to 1.0.3 - see [this issue](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4864) (thanks Blaze Sahlzen).